# Cache emited value when using async pipe to be able to filter out future emits

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to cache the emitted value of an observable to filter out irrelevant future emits.

I have a route:

```
{ path: "user/:id/:type", component: UserComponent }
```

Within that component i'm getting the `ActivatedRoute` params, `switchMap` to the actual http call, and using `async` pipe on template to show the user details.

```
user$: Observable<User>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.route.params.pipe(
       switchMap(params => {
         return this.http.getUser(params.id)
       })
    );
}
```

in the template it self:

```
<div *ngIf="user$ | async as user"> 
   <span>{{ user.id }}</span>
   <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
</div>
```

I would like to filter out `this.route.params` values, if the route changes but the `:id` param stays the same.

I was thinking something like

```
user$: Observable<User>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.route.params.pipe(
       withLatestFrom(this.user$ || Observable.from({})),
       filter( ([params, user]) => {
           return (params.id !== user.id); // filter if params id equals to last fetched user
       }),
       switchMap(params => {
         return this.http.getUser(params.id)
       })
    );
}
```

but `withLatestFrom` comes up null.
i would like to avoid caching it using a tap operator, and just come up with a clean alternative, somewhere like the road i tried to take. what am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare the value only with the last emission, you could use RxJS `pluck` operator to select the `id` property and `distinctUntilChanged` operator to ignore the notifications until the `id` is changed.

Try the following

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.route.params.pipe(
       pluck('id'),
       distinctUntilChanged(),
       switchMap(id => {
         return this.http.getUser(id)
       })
    );
}
```

Or to ignore all the duplicates and trigger the HTTP request only for distinct `id`s, you could RxJS `distinct` operator.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.route.params.pipe(
       distinct(params => params['id']),
       switchMap(params => {
         return this.http.getUser(params.id)
       })
    );
}
```

Comment: you are a genius.